# How can I achieve operator agnostic call barring?

Tags: root-access, 5.1-lollipop, system-apps

so, I've got a rooted Samsung G800F.

My objective:

- The phone has access to mobile data (not WiFi). (Intended for
  streaming Amazon and Youtube and maybe a bit of surfing or
  tethering.)
- The phone can not be called. Ideally the phone can not call or get/send sms and install other applications.
- The calls do not get blocked. (They are intended for a second cell using the same
  number/contract.)

What I tried so far and deem useless:

- Call Barring (My operator does not support this.)
- Call Blocking (My
  other phone has no chance to answer the calls.)
- Do not disturb/silent
  mode (It could still be answered and the calls are still visually
  signalled.)

What I'm trying now:
Fiddling around with the phone app.

And here I'm absolutely lost and hope you can lend me a helping hand.

So, I tried Titanium, but couldn't identify the correct app. I froze and killed some suspiciously sounding/looking ones, but calls still went through and the ringer went uninterrupted.

Next I installed "Root Uninstaller"
Here I found com.android.phone and had some partial success with killing this or some services.

There are two problems though:

1. I do not know what I'm doing. Not a clue. So, can you tell me what service to disable?
2. When I reboot the device it has problems and constantly displays an error message/is almost unusable.
3. (Falling under the "ideally"-category: can I just freeze some "Play"-App to prevent installation of messengers - relying on the phone number - and such?)

(Just FYI: I'm from Europe and might read and respond at odd-seeming times.
 I wanted to include the tag call-barring, feel free to add this.)

Comment: I simply can't understand your question. What is the `Question`?

Comment: Hm.. sorry..

How can I set this device up as to allow disturbance-free streaming while still being able to answer those calls on another handset pertaining to the same number/contract?

Answer (score 0):

That's probably not possible at the moment, as you'd have to forward the calls using VoIP. This is way too complicated to implement on your own, as these features are already builtin to the mobile network.

Alternatively your MNO may have some USSD codes for automatic call forwarding, so you need to look if those are available to you.

*Unconditional* [Call Forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_forwarding) is usually activated with:
`*21*[phone number]#` and cancelled with `##21#`. For other options, check the link.

[Call Barring](http://www.geckobeach.com/cellular/secrets/gsmcodes.php):

> If you wish to restrict calls that can be made or received by your handset then this is referred to as "Call Barring". All Call Barring codes are specific to your network, so you'll have to ask your service provider

Also check [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unstructured_Supplementary_Service_Data)

Comment: As I understand it, call forwarding would not work as both handsets use the same mobile number and subscription.
My operator does not support Call Barring via the network. 

That is why I'm trying to disable basic telephony by tinkering with the software.

Comment: If what you want to do is to have both phones with same number, you are talking about SIM cloning, which apart from being illegal almost everywhere, is very hard to do. This is not the forum for this.

Comment: My operator readily supplies Multi SIMs, there is nothing fishy about that.
If those are "cloned" cards I don't know, they have different SIM card numbers for example. 
Still, they pertain to one and the same contract and phone number.
So I can use all services with both cards. (Except SMS, those are send to the main card AFAIK.)

Comment: Who's your operator? I've never heard of such a thing as 2 SIM cards using the same number, except in cloning attacks. This clearly goes against the Mobile (and SIM) standard of operations. Also Google for osmocom. I think they did some research on this, some years ago.

Comment: Telekom Deutschland, a completely normal operator.

Check this out:
https://www.telekom.de/unterwegs/tarife-und-optionen/multisim

>> With the MultiSIM, you extend your Telekom mobile phone contract by up to two additional SIM cards and are therefore available on several devices.

    One phone number, one tariff and one invoice for all cards
    Allowance options apply to all cards
    No messy switching of the SIM cards into other devices
    Parallel phone calls, surfing and e-mailing

Comment: `I've never heard of such a thing as 2 SIM cards using the same number` plenty of such carriers. In Ukraine we have this too